# How to echo data from JSON that is inside a function?

Tags: php, json

```
function fbPageCounter()
{
    $link = "https://graph.facebook.com/google?fields=name,likes&access_token=ID|SECRET";
    $gData = file_get_contents($link);
    $gData = json_decode($gData);

    return $gData;
}
```

Without it being in a function I can echo it like this: `$fbData->{'likes'}`

Since it is now into a function, how do I echo the likes data?

UPDATE:

I'd like to know how to return the data by echoing it with the function like so: `echo fbPageCounter();` not sure what goes inside to return the likes or name..

Comment: What has it being in a function got to do with `echo` ??

Comment: just return the data with `return` keyword, eg `return $gData->{someprop};` basically just replace your previous (before function use) `echo` with `return`

Comment: @Steve, would it not be something like this? echo googlePageCounter->{'likes'}; since the data has been returned from the function?

Comment: @iBrazilian2 if you return the complete object , eg `return $fbData;` then you can access the properties where its called; `echo fbPageCounter()->{likes};` Alternitivly return the specific propery `return $fbData->{likes};` then echo the result of the function: `echo fbPageCounter();

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

For a dynamic approach capable of accessing multiple properties, perhaps a nice solution is a class? Might be overkill but depending on what you need it to do, might not be?

```
class FbPageCounter {
    // Stores json data from FB
    public $gData;

    // Set $gData
    public function __construct() {
        $link = "https://graph.facebook.com/google?fields=name,likes&access_token=ID|SECRET";
        $gData = file_get_contents($link);
        $this->gData = json_decode($gData);
    }

    // Returns likes
    public function getLikes() {
        return $this->gData->{'likes'};
    }

    // Returns name
    public function getName() {
        return $this->gData->{'name'};
    }
}

$n = new FbPageCounter();
echo $n->getLikes();
echo $n->getName();
```